# Creating a first visit popover menu, state not updating in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, popup, popover

I have a created popover menu, and I am trying to add the functionality of displaying this popover menu on the first visit to a page with the component. My idea was to use useEffect() and localStorage, however it seems that changes made to my usePopover() state do not seem to be saving.

```
const { showed, toggle, hide, show } = usePopover()

useEffect(() => {

  if(!localStorage["alreadyVisited"]) {
    localStorage["alreadyVisited"] = true;
    show
  }

}, [show])
```

Edit: The solution ended up being that I needed to change `show` to `show()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving nor calling the storage , this is how should be done :

```
useEffect(() => {

  if(!localStorage.getItem("alreadyVisited")) {
    localStorage.setItem("alreadyVisited",true) 
    show
  }

}, [show])
```

use this as a ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage